# Pass context to many2many field

Tags: python, odoo

Hi I am trying to pass the value from a Many2many field to a Many2many field using the context attribute in the view.

```
<field name="vehicules" widget="one2many_list" context="{ 'default_problems':(6,0, problems)}">
```

default_problems and problems are both Many2many fields, I tried also (1,problems), but in both case only 1 element of the Many2many field is passed from problems to default_problems.

Please some help, I am blocked with this and can't find a solution.

Comment: Have you debugged into JavaScript or Pythonside (Method BaseModel.default_get()) and looked what values will be set into context? I'm just wondering, because i never tried something like that so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing `many2many` field in context it is evaluated to:

```
[[6, False, list_of_ids]]
```

You do not have to use the special `commands` format. You only have to specify the name of the field:

```
<field name="vehicules" widget="one2many_list" context="{ 'default_problems': problems}">
```

Comment: I am glad to help you.